# GitHub workflows - how to keep project up-to-date and passwords secure?

Tags: php, git, security, github

I'm about to opensource a PHP based website on GitHub

Contained within it are my MySql DB passwords and API keys (contained within a separate config file)

I can remove these to upload to GitHub, but how would I then make future changes and deploy to the production server? - currently the I pull the latest commit from a private git repo.

Now I'm using a public repo, I can't pull the latest committed changes as the passwords / API keys will be missing.

Would I use a combination of the 2 repositories and git-ignore the config file (i.e. push to both, but leave out the config for the public repo)? Or should I not be using Git to deploy to the production server in the first place?

Many thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only push a config- sample in the repo and gitignore the "real" config, because every instance will have its own config. After you deployed the repo on your production system you copy/create the config based on the sample, fill in your "personal" settings and you are done.